# How do I access my config variable in my helper file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, config, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I’m using rails 5.  I have this defined in my config/environments/development.rb file

```
config.hostname = “myapp.com"
```

and then I try and access this in a helper file by using

```
url = "https://#{config.hostname}/lti"
```

but this results in an error,

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for ScenariosHelper:Module
```

How do I access my config variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Rails configuration through `Rails.configuration`, so use:

```
Rails.configuration.hostname
```

Comment: To take this answer further, please note that the variable `config` in development.rb is a block variable for Rails.configuration:  `Rails.configuration do |config|`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
url = "https://#{Rails.configuration.hostname}/lti"
```